# How to use standalone correctly? Scaling issue between standalone and \input

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, external-files, standalone

I have to deal with multiple rather large tikz images which I'd like to run isolated as a standalone file. Now, when integrating these images into my main file, the scaling is off. Meaning that I obtain different results depending on whether I use

```
\includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{...}
```

or

```
\input{...}
```

I attached a minimum working example to illustrate my issue:

main file:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{images/FullPlot}
\input{images/FullPlot}
\end{document}
```

tikz-image file in the sub folder .../images/

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.85\columnwidth]
\node at (1,1) {SampleText};
\addplot [color=black, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\ 2 2\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

How could I make the standalone image respect the format of the main file, so in this case the two-column and general format of the main class? Ultimately, I just want standalone to produce the same result as \input but in comparison only compile the file if I changed anything from the last time. And are there other best practices to look out for?

I really appreciate any helpful answers and comments!

Comment: Evidently [buildnew] compares the source date to the image (PDF) date, and uses the image if newer.  If you make a gratuitous change to the source WITHOUT testing it, [buildnew] will work like \input, but will NOT update the image.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is the result of `\input` but without the TeX compiling this external file everytime, then I would take a look at the tikzexternalise tikz library.

```latex
\usetikzlibrary{external}
```

It compiles any tikz in your document separately, keeping the result in a cache folder. Each tikz picture is only updated when changes are made to that picture. You don't need to change anything in your LaTeX code, and it works with external and internal tikz files.

Requires LaTeX to have have shell escape enabled. Something like:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

I find it is a bit janky sometimes, but it greatly speeds up compilation on documents with many tikz diagrams and plots.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used to have issues with tikzexternalize but it's been a while. Are you sure that it automatically refreshes the pdf if the source file is newer? I remember having to delete the corresponding pdf to enforce a new compilation. Overall, I'd still rather go with standalone but if there is no way to solve the problem above it seems I will have to switch back to tikzexternalize.

Comment: I have used it to write my thesis submitted yesterday and 99% of the time it would update the pdf automatically when the source file was changed. Very occasionally things would break and I'd have to delete the cache but it saved me an immense amount of time in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all the standalone package does is cause `\input` to ignore all the code which would normally cause errors (`\documentclass ... \begin{document}` and the corresponding `\end{document}`).  It does **not** run standalone using a shell-escape.

If you use document class dependent values (like `\columnwidth`) and you want to use that image repeatedly, you will need to feed that information to the standalone source.  The easiest way is manually.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\AtBeginDocument{\columnwidth=252pt}% depends on document class
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.85\columnwidth]
\node at (axis cs: 1,1) {\the\columnwidth};
\addplot [color=black, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\ 2 2\\
};
\end{axis}
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Since you will need to run the above build anyway, you might as well use `\includegraphics` instead of `\includestandalone` in the main document.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}% for \input version
\usepackage{standalone}% for \input version
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent\includegraphics{test6}

\noindent\input{test6}% for comparison
\end{document}
```